# Far Harbor settlements

Tags: fallout-4

I am trying to build settlements in Far Harbor. I have activated the fog condensers but it says I need to clear the fog. I assumed that I had done that with all the collectors.

How do I clear the fog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered this message while doing a quest yesterday, I think this is just the game being unclear about what you have to do.

If I'm right this is the second part of the [Blood Tide](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Blood_Tide) quest for Cassie Dalton where you have to kill the Fog Crawler in Dalton Farm.

In this case, try going back to Cassie and turn in the quest. You'll then get access to the workshop.

Comment: No, its the first settlement along the east coast, it isn't part of a quest and it isn't the settlement with the fog crawler, however i did wander upon that one too.

Comment: Strange, seems the message is used for several settlements then. I guess the requirements may depend on the settlement.

Comment: Ill try to find out more later, thanks you for your help.